# Htaccess domain redirect fails for subfolders with same name

Tags: .htaccess

I'm setting up a multi-site where I'm redirecting site2.com to a subfolder in site1.com, but I'm having a lot of trouble with the htaccess redirect. 
Site2.com is pointed by DNS to Site1.com, where a htaccess file takes care of the redirect on the server. The basic setup is this:

```
Site 1:
/public_html/

Site 2:
/public_html/site2/
```

The htaccess redirect method I'm currently using in /public_html/ (site1.com) is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site2/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site2/index.html [L]
```

The basic redirect works fine, even for subfolders under site2. However, if I have a subfolder under each site with the same name, the redirect fails, like so:

```
/public_html/subfolder/
/public_html/site2/subfolder/
```

If I try to access www.site2.com/subfolder/ this renders /public_html/subfolder/ and not /public_html/site2/subfolder/

Comment: Do you have a rule at the top that looks something like this:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

You should disable multiviews with `Options -MultiViews`